# Wordpress Widget not saving

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I'm trying to save a simple widget, however everytime I hit save, it does not save the values. Instead the form is refreshed to a default value.

The code is below.

**What I have found is that the value of `$instance` in the `update()` function is an empty array i.e. `array()` why is this??**

```
<?php 

defined('ABSPATH') or die("Cannot access pages directly.");

defined("DS") or define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget("Page_Widget");' ) );
add_action( 'admin_head', 'page_widget_admin_head' );

$pw_class = new Page_Widget();
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pw_get_option', array($pw_class, 'get_options'));
add_action( 'wp_ajax_pw_get_option',  array($pw_class, 'get_options'));

function page_widget_admin_head()
    {

    if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) != 'widgets.php'){return false; }

    echo '<style> .titler { width:80px; display:inline-block; }</style>';

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">

                            jQuery(function($){

                                  $(".post_type_select").live("change", function(){
                                                                        the_opt = $(this).val();
                                                                        el = $(this);
                                                                        $.post(ajaxurl, "action=pw_get_option&pw_post_type="+the_opt, function(data){

                                                                                                el.siblings(".posts_select").html(data);  

                                                                                                                                           })

                                                                                 });


                                  });</script>';


    }

/**
 * 
 * @author byrd
 * Document Widget
 */
class Page_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * Registers the widget details with the parent class
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        // widget actual processes
        parent::__construct( $id = 'page_widget', $name = 'Page Widget', $options = array( 'description' => 'A Widget for grabbing page ids' ) );
    }

    function form($instance)
    {
        // outputs the options form on admin
        $post_type_str = '<span class="titler">Post Type: </span><select name="pw_post_type" class="post_type_select">';        
        $post_types = get_post_types(array('public' => true),' objects'); 
        $i = 1;

        $pw_post_type = '';
        $pw_post_id = '';

        error_log(var_export($instance, true));

        if ( $instance ) {

            $pw_post_type = esc_attr( $instance[ 'pw_post_type' ] );
            $pw_post_id = esc_attr( $instance[ 'pw_post_id' ] );

        }

        foreach ($post_types as $post_type ) {

          $name = $post_type->labels->name;
          $var  = $post_type->name;

              if($i == 1){$first = $var; }
              if($pw_post_type == $var){$selected  = 'selected="selected"'; }else{$selected = ''; }

              $post_type_str .= '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$var.'">'. $name. '</option>';
              $i++;

        }

        $options = $this->get_options($first, $pw_post_id);
        $post_type_str .= '</select><br/><span class="titler">Post Name: </span><select name="pw_post_id" class="posts_select">'.$options.'</select>';

        echo $post_type_str;

    }

    function get_options($post_type = false, $pw_post_id = '', $ajax = false)
    {   

        if(!$post_type){ $post_type = $_POST['pw_post_type']; $ajax = true; }

        $args = array('numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => $post_type);
        $str = '';
        $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $posts_array as $post ) 
        {   
            if($pw_post_id == $post->ID){$selected  = 'selected="selected"'; }else{ $selected = ''; }
            $str .= '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$post->ID.'">'.$post->post_title.'</option>';
        }

        if($ajax){ echo $str; exit(); }
        else{ return $str; }

    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        error_log(var_export($new_instance, true));
        error_log(var_export($old_instance, true));
        // processes widget options to be saved
        $instance = wp_parse_args($old_instance, $new_instance);
        return $new_instance;
    }

    function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        // outputs the content of the widget


    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you asked this a while ago, but I'll answer in case others follow along.

Make sure you're using:

```
$field_name = $this->get_field_name('your_field_name');
```

when creating field names for your widget form items.  The field names need to conform to WordPress' naming conventions.  Otherwise, you'll get nothing back from the form post.

Answer (score 0):

Change your class name which is

```
class Page_Widget extends WP_Widget
```

to this

```
class WP_Widget_Page_Widget extends WP_Widget
```

and also change this line

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget("Page_Widget");' ) );
```

to

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget("WP_Widget_Page_Widget ");' ) );
```

This will work insaAllah.